# Emacs custom shell commands

Tags: shell, emacs, command

Is there a possability in Emacs to run custom commands or a set of commands (eg. shell) with a user defined emacs shortcut/hook?
To make this clearer. I am working with an embedded system (target), but developing on the host. After writing and compiling code (eg using emacs compile command), I would like to copy (eg. scp) the binary to the system right away.
Furthermore it would be good if the custom shorcut/hook would be easy to adjust (eg. ip address of the target).

Btw: I am aware of the "shell-command" in emacs, but that is not quite what I am looking for.

Would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: There appear to be insufficient details to answer the question.  You can use the `start-process` family of functions to run your own shell commands, and you can also call a script (if you so choose).  If you need to wait until a process finishes before starting the next you can use `set-process-sentinel`.

Comment: As others already said, there is not enough details in your question. I am shooting in the dark here.  Are you aware that you can define your own functions in Emacs using the built-in Emacs Lisp language?  You could add them to Emacs' initialization files.  This link to the Emacs documentation describes how to: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Functions.html

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response. I think the question is quite specific, but lets just assume that i want to run the following shell command "scp my-file root@my-target-ip:/tmp/". my-file should be the file in the current buffer and my-target-ip should be an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `C-x C-f /root@my-target-ip:/tmp/myfile` to edit the file directly on the target. Then you can run it with `shell-command ./myfile` from within emacs.